# How can I delete small objects by using bwareaopen?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image and I want to delete black pixels which are on the big white objects. I use `bwareaopen(BW,P)` function but it deletes only hole objects not black pixels on them. I tried for different `P` values but again fail.

Why `bwareopen` cannot delete the black pixels on white objects and how can I delete them?

The image:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bwareaopen()` removes *white* areas with size less than `p`. 
If you want to remvove the *black* holes inside your white areas you should use the function `imfill()` .

Edit: Alternativly, you could use the `bwareaopen()` function on the inverse image, i.e. on `1-Im`